# Query a column based on current date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

I'm trying to query a column based on the current day.

Examples:

If today is 1st day of the month I need to:

```
=QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE B CONTAINS 'this text'")
```

If today is 12th day of the month I need to:

```
=QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE M CONTAINS 'this text'")
```

If today is 30th day of the month I need to

```
=QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE AE CONTAINS 'this text'")
```

How can I do this?

I was thinking about adding `+1` to the current day, converting it to its corresponding letter and using it in the query.
But I have no idea how to actually do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following `QUERY` formulas:

If today is 1st day of the month:

```
=IF(DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)=1,QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE B CONTAINS 'this text'")," ")
```

If today is 12th day of the month:

```
=IF(DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+12)=12,QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE M CONTAINS 'this text'")," ")
```

If today is 30th day of the month:

```
=IF(DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+30)=30,QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE AE CONTAINS 'this text'")," ")
```

How the formula works:

- `TODAY()`= **today's date**.
- `EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)`= **last day of last month**.
- `DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1)`= **1st day of this month** *(last day of last month + 1 day)*.

So, the **12th day of this month** is: **`DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+12)`**

---

**PRO TIPS**:

1. The last day of this month (either 28th or 29th or 30th or 31st) is always `=DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)`
2. If you place the date of the `IF` function in a cell outside the query In eg. cell `A1` you can have numbers like `1` or `12` or `25` etc and change your query to:

```
=IF(DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+A1)=A1,QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE M CONTAINS 'this text'")," ")
```

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`TODAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)
- [`EOMONTH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093044)
- [`DAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093040)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I need 1 cell to display data for today.
If it's the first day I need it to display data from A where B contains text. If it's the second day I need it to display data from A where C contains text, and so on for the whole month.
I need that cell to detect what's day today and display data for that day.

Comment: Please check the updated answer for ore info and tips.

Comment: If this answer is not what you are looking for, please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Code that you gave me gives me #VALUE!

But ere is the example sheet of what I'm trying to get
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14CElf7FeVDNGxAfqGgN-fiqz3bCpOPguB3lONdcJ00Y/edit#gid=0

Data for each day are stored in Sheet1
And Sheet2 needs to show selected data for today and tomorow

Because today is 9th day, that corresponds to column "E" from Sheet1, and I need to show data that contains "x", so I used =QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE E CONTAINS 'x'")

Comment: And because tomorow is 10th day of the month, that corresponds to column "F" from Sheet1, and I need to show data that contains "z", so I used =QUERY(table,"SELECT A WHERE F CONTAINS 'z'")

This way I have to manually update code every day.
I want sheet to detect current day and automatically assign corresponding column letter from Sheet1

Comment: Haven't checked you sheet yet, but could this be what you are looking for? `=QUERY({B2:N11},"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col"&DAY(A1)&" CONTAINS 'this'")`

Comment: That code still gives me errors
I need a code that when pasted in A2 on Sheet2 will today give me "data1" and "data3" as output, but tomorrow will give me "data3" and "data5" and day after tomorrow it should give me "data2" and "data5"